# how to change the location of node modules in gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to change the location of the gulp module something out of the project directory, can we change the default location that i.e.

from

```
node_modules/gulp
node_modules/gulp-uglify
```

to

```
../node_modules/gulp
../node_modules/gulp-uglify
```

Comment: First, ask your self if your "fighting the framework". Why do you feel you need to depart from the community standards? After that, try setting the NODE_PATH environment variable.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?